# how to retrieve ids of 5 oldest users from the user table (given id,name,created_at)

Tags: mysql, sql

select id from users order by min;

select id from users order by limit 5;

Answer (score 1):

You **select which columns you want** to query. In your case: `id`. And you specify **from which table you want** to query: `users`.

```sql
select id from users
```

Using the `limit x` command - where x is a number - you will get the first x records. In your case, you need the 5 oldest ids, i.e., the 5 items created earliest according to their `created_at` date. Therefore, we need to sort the list in ascending order based on the `created_at` date:

```
2022-01-01
2022-01-02
2022-01-03
etc.
```

This can be done with the `order by` command. However, `order by` needs to know **which column to sort the records** in descending order. Since you could also sort the records alphabetically by name, but we want to sort them by `created_at` now.
For more information about the "order by" keyword: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

```sql
select id from users order by created_at
```

And we are **only interested in the first 5 records**: `limit 5`

```sql
-- |         |         |                   |          |

   select id from users order by created_at limit 5

-- |         |         |                   |          |
-- | columns |  table  |  order_by_column  | how much |
-- |         |         |                   |          |
```